# Create Laravel Relationship through Many-To-One and Many-To-Many

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm having trouble defining a relationship between several models.
In the Laravel documentation, I was able to find a [hasManyThrough()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship where the relationship was extended down through two many-to-one models, but I'm having issues with mine from a many-to-one then many-to-many relationship. Here are the tables:

```
practices
  id
  name

locations
  id
  practice_id
  name

doctors
  id
  name

doctor_location
  doctor_id
  location_id
```

As you can see, practices can have many locations, and locations can only belong to one practice. Doctors can have many locations, and locations can have many doctors. I'm not certain how to drill down to create a `$practice->doctors` relationship, however. I did attempt the hasManyThrough() relationship in the practices model:

```
public function doctors() {
  return $this->hasManyThrough(Doctor::class, Location::class);
}
```

but this simply threw an sqlstate error looking for a location_id in the doctors table. Is it possible to relate these models?

Edit: SQLState error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'doctors.location_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `doctors`.*, `locations`.`practice_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `doctors` inner join `locations` on `locations`.`id` = `doctors`.`location_id` where `locations`.`practice_id` = 1)
```

Comment: can you provide the whole error message you are getting

Comment: @AmrMonier Certainly - updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message and the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) are clear.
`hasManyThrough` relation works only with **one to many** relations

`Practices` -> `Locations` is **one to many** but `Locations` -> `Doctors`
is **many to many** there is a pivot table between Locations and Doctors. therefore you can't use `hasManyThrough` in this scenario

if you really want to use `hasManyThrough`, you must convert the `Locations` -> `Doctors` relation to **one to many** by placing **location_id** in the **doctors** table

Otherwise the only way the get the doctors is like @Bulent suggested

```
$practice = Practice::where("id", your_id )->with('locations.doctors')->first();
```

and then iterate thought locations and doctors

```
foreach ($practice->locations as $location) {
    foreach ($location->doctors as $doctor) {
        // do stuff with each doctor here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need any relationship between doctors and practice in your case. The following query should work:

```
Practice::with('locations.doctors');
```

The output should be an array of locations, and each location will contain doctors.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'doctors.location_id'

The query which is executed is trying to perform a join between `doctors` and `locations` tables

```
select `doctors`.*, `locations`.`practice_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `doctors` inner join `locations` on `locations`.`id` = `doctors`.`location_id` where `locations`.`practice_id` = 1)
```

The query use this clause to perform the join

```
inner join `locations` on `locations`.`id` = `doctors`.`location_id`
```

As you `doctors` table doesn't have a `location_id` attribute this is the main cause of that error.

This error is because you have have define the `hasManyThrough` relation using wrong models, It should be like this

```
public function doctors() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Doctor::class, DoctorLocation::class);
}
```

This supposed you have already define a model `DoctorLocation` which refered to the `doctor_location` table. This will allow you to access doctors from from **Practice**

This will allow eloquent to perform the `join` between **Practice** and **Doctor** by passing through the **doctor_location** table as it has `location_id` and `doctor_id` attributes.